# Run one-time, async callback before all junit tests

Tags: android, junit, robolectric

I would like to call some methods before run all tests.
Library provides initializer which preparing device to use:

```
    SomeLibraryInitializer.init(new SomeLibraryInitializer.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

        }
    });
```

The library is ready to use when onFinish is called.

Can't mock library classes (proguard in use), so I have to use that initializer for my `JUnit tests`.

Is there any way to wait until callback `onFinish()` is called?

Tried with  `ShadowApplication.runBackgroundTasks();` and Semaphore, but not seem to work.
I'm using `@BeforeClass` Annotation to run it before all tests.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to extend [AndroidJUnitRunner](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/runner/AndroidJUnitRunner.html) and then set it int `build.gradle` file like

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        testInstrumentationRunner "com.example.MyTestRunner"
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

If you look at the [source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/testing/+/android-support-test/runner/src/main/java/android/support/test/runner/AndroidJUnitRunner.java#194) you will see `onCreate` method that is called once. What you want to do is owerride this method and add your own logic in it. Then when you are done you should call `start()` metho.

Comment: I don't understand how can it resolve my problem. Could you please provide example?